# Python dataframe axis with sum() and apply() are working differently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe like below

```
    Seoul   Busan
    Green   Red Green
    a   1   0   1   2
        2   3   4   5
    b   1   6   7   8
        2   9   10  11
```

When I execute **df.sum(axis=0, level=0), it executes row by row**, so result is

```
Seoul   Busan
Green   Red Green
a   3   5   7
b   15  17  19
```

But **when I execute df.apply(print,axis=0),it prints column by column**

```
a  1    0
   2    3
b  1    6
   2    9
Name: (Seoul, Green), dtype: int32
a  1     1
   2     4
b  1     7
   2    10
Name: (Seoul, Red), dtype: int32
a  1     2
   2     5
b  1     8
   2    11
Name: (Busan, Green), dtype: int32
```

Why does difference happend though same as 'axis=0'? Could you explain to me?

Comment: Can you provide the data in a more convenient format? I would recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391.

Comment: It actually is the same thing. `sum(axis=0)` sums along the (different) indexes, `apply(axis=0)` applies along the (different) indexes. That said, I understand why people, me included, get confused sometimes.

Comment: Another intuitive/readable approach that works with pandas methods is to pass `axis="columns"` or `axis="rows"`. instead of 0 or 1. Remember you pass an axis, the function will operate *across* that axis, not within it.

Answer (score 0):

When you **sum** along *axis=0*, you compute sums along each column,
but the result is a **single** DataFrame, containing sums (with
rows for each index a level *0*).

But **apply** with *axis=0* means actually: Apply the given method
to each column in turn (and collect results).

Note that *print* only prints its arguments.
From the point of view of *apply* it returns *None*, so:

- the actual result of *apply*, for each column, is *None*,
- the content of each column printed is a **side effect**.

To confirm it run `xx = df.apply(print,axis=0)`
and you will see the same printout.

Then run `print(xx)` and you will see:

```
Seoul  Green    None
Busan  Red      None
       Green    None
dtype: object
```

i.e. just the *None* results from *print* invocation for each column.